# Chrome browser says "No devices found" when I try to cast to a Chromecast

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, chromecast

I just set up a Google Chromecast using the Google Home app on my iPhone.  Then I tried the Cast feature in the Chrome browser on my Windows 10 laptop PC, which is connected to the same Wi-Fi network as the Chromecast, and got a "No devices found" error in the Cast tab.  How do I get Chrome on my PC to find my Chromecast?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the error by right-clicking on the casting icon and clicking on the "Optimize fullscreen videos" option.

[image]

Now the Cast tab displays my Chromecast device.

Another thing that may cause the "No devices found" error is if you are connected to a VPN.

Answer (score 6):

In Chrome browser enter `chrome://flags/` into the address bar and search and enable:

- `Cast Media Route Provider` -> `enable`.

If it doesn't help:

- `Connect to Cast devices on all IP addresses` -> `enable`

If it doesn't help:

- `Load Media Router Component Extension` -> `enable`

Comment: "Connect to Cast devices on all IP addresses" was the only option available to me out of those 3, and it didn't help, unfortunately. Casting to Roku used to work but suddenly stopped working for me today, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: "Connect to Cast devices on all IP addresses"  Yep... it turns out that Chrome normally disables Chromecast when you have real public IP addresses, by default.  After spending an hour staring at packets with Wireshark trying to figure out WTF as it was actually working at that layer, turns out Chrome was filtering them.  This solved it.  Thanks so much!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the underlying problem was that for historical reasons my LAN is not numbered from the RFC-1918 range of IP addresses.  Therefore, this part of Frank Breitling's answer was absolutely crucial

```
Connect to Cast devices on all IP addresses -> enabled
```

That this is not the default is absolutely daft, but there we are.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an intermittent issue, such as mine, you may find that you need to reboot the PC and wait longer before logging in.  If I log into my PC too rapidly, it will be unable to find my Chromecast until I reboot and let it sit longer.  Around 5 minutes at the login screen seems to be sufficient.